# How to load android binaries in Debian environment?

Tags: exec, ld, linker

I am trying to run `adbd` from within a chrooted environment. I can run it fine with Android's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./linker64 $PWD/adbd`.

When I try to run `./adbd` I get:
`bash: ./adbd: cannot execute: required file not found`.

Running with `strace $PWD/adbd` returns:

```bash
execve("/root/adbd", ["/root/adbd"], 0x7fcfe8dfd0 /* 8 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: exec: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

What dynamic linker is missing and on which path?

Answer (score 0):

I ran `readelf --all ./adbd | grep link` and it turns out that the output is:
`[Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker64]`